# InDesign auto numbering issue

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design

I am working on Indesign project contains 20 pages and I applied auto numbering for pages.

If I want to export pdf from my project but I want page 1 and page 20 on same spread, page 2 and page 19 on same spread and so on.

Is there any exporting option to do like this or, I need to make numbering manually and delete the auto numbering?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Are you sending the PDF off to a printer for printing? If so, you probably **don’t** want to impose the document—the printer will do that for you. Even most office copy-printers have a booklet function that will automatically impose documents for you. It's nearly always a bad (or at least unnecessary) idea to impose a document yourself.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to impose a document for booklet printing. Luckily, InDesign has this feature built in. To get an imposed PDF, do the following:

1. File -> Print Booklet
2. Make sure the booklet type is 2-Up Saddle Stitch
3. Click Print Settings
4. Change the printer to PostScript File
5. Edit the rest of the printer settings to match your project, if necessary
6. Click Ok
7. Click Preview in the sidebar to make sure it looks how you expect
8. Click Print
9. It will save a file with the extension *.indd.ps
10. Open the newly created file in Acrobat Pro, and save it as a .pdf

Source: https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/printing-booklets.html